# How to make a form that sends answers to a different page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a attendance webpage for my school because the one they use right now is not so efficient.
Basically, the teachers get logins and they use a checkbox to specify wether a student is absent or not. (I'm using Bootstrap Toggle)
I want there to be a page that when the teacher presses submit, the data from the current page on absent students goes to a 'manage' page, so it says the students that are absent from what class.

Basically I need to send the checkbox's state to a different page. Whats the easiest way to do this?

Comment: Might want to check out this article: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: You have to use HTTP request but.. u have to make a better question... can you post the html of the page??!

Comment: So you want to have one page where the teacher can mark students absent, then another that shows a list of classes and what students were absent from them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way I would do it is by placing an ajax call. I would make a javascript function that collects information from checkboxes i.e. ids of those students who are absent and then send those ids to a manage page which would have a php function to process it. I dont know what kind of pages you are using, but you're asking the easiest way of doing it, so this how I would do it.

```
 function getCheckBoxInfo()
 {
     ///code here to iterate through checkboxes and
     // find those that are checked/unchecked +
   // their respective ids or names (e.g. value fields in html), 
     //  google - looping through checkboxes

  // then you place them in a number of variables
 /// i would create maybe 10-15 variables, i dont think
 /// more than that would be absent
   //and then you send those variable to managePage.php
  //using this ajax call

 if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
    xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   }
  else
   {// code for IE6, IE5
   xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
   }
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
   if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;

     }
   }
   xmlhttp.open("GET","managePage.php?var1="+var1+"&var2="+var2,true);
  xmlhttp.send();
   }
```

Then in managePage.php you extract those variables: var1 = $_GET["var1"].

You may also want to look into jquery ajax calls, they are more compact.

You can also google - sending data from javascript via ajax call to a php page.